# IPad - Crashing with no apparent reason

Tags: ipad

I know it's a bit weird but I have no code at all to put here, unless I copy all of it.
My project is crashing with no apparent reason. I've read this solution: [iPhone application is crashing and not leaving behind a .crash log file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/783782/iphone-application-is-crashing-and-not-leaving-behind-a-crash-log-file)

and I'm using Instrument for searching for leaks and other possibilities for those crashes.
Another strange thing is: even when I run my app with debug on XCode, it just stop to work on my IPad but it looks it is still running.

And the last and more strange thing: there's no crash log at all on my device. Before somebody ask, it is enable to record crash logs.

Does anybody have any idea for helping me?

Regards

Comment: When you say 'crash', what do you mean? Does the app quit or freeze? What is shown on the display? Have you tried restarting the device completely, deleting the app from it, restarting Xcode, cleaning the target, and building again? How recently was this working, and what have you changed since then? What are the heavier/more dangerous tasks in your code? Does it work in the simulator?

Comment: @Luke: Crash = quit. On display: last line is written (gdb). Yes, I did everything you told me in this part. I got all code back to the more trustfull code I had. The more dangerous is changing views and rotate the IPad. In the simulator it's working perfectly!

Answer (score 0):

I've had this happen to me before on various platforms. If its crashing on you, whether its an iPhone app, openGL / DirectX program, try these steps:

1. Have you tried to undo your last change and get to the point where it last worked?
2. Have you tried placing a print outputs to the terminal to see how far your program is executing? Start at the beginning and work your way into your program. This is especially useful when there is no crash log.

Also in particular to iPhone apps: Have you checked your xib's? Did you recently re-factor and change the name of a class maybe? You might need to re-link your nib to your classes. This on more than one occasion has caused apps of mine to crash with no error. Hope this helps.

Comment: 1. Yes, I did. 2. Yes, actually there're plenty of NSLog's on my app. Is it possible that these NSLog are crashing my app? all xib's are really fine.

Comment: From one of your comments I see that it works in the simulator and not the device. It could be that your Xcode is out of date as well as the simulator? You might be using a piece of deprecated code which works on older versions but not newer versions. Without the code its hard to tell.

Comment: Not at all, I'm using XCode 4.0.2.

Comment: Unfortunately this is much harder to solve without any code. Even then I doubt its the code, it might be a build setting. It may be best to contact apple at this point.

Also maybe you figured it out already too?

Comment: I just figured out other weird thing: the same code using an IPad 2(same version of iOS) is not crashing! Hardware performance?

Answer (score 0):

I doubt you are still wondering about this, but my answer is that you were experiencing your app getting killed by the OS due to using too much memory. This will silently fail in the log in my experience when running on the device.

You will have to go into the Organizer to the device console and crash reports that get stored on the device to see the clues.

The reason your crash stopped when you got an iPad 2 is because the iPad 2 has twice the memory of the iPad 1 (which is dramatically under-stocked with RAM)